# Vue + TypeScript + Firebase: How to Type an object containing a `ref` of a firebase `User`?

Tags: typescript, firebase, vue.js

I have a function that is returning an object containing a `ref` of a firebase `User`, the `ref` can also be `null`.

How do I define the return Type of this function?

Here is my simple Vue composable with the offending code:

```
import { ref, Ref } from "vue";
import { projectAuth } from "@/firebase/config";
import { User, onAuthStateChanged } from "firebase/auth";

const user = ref<null | User>(projectAuth.currentUser);

onAuthStateChanged(projectAuth, (_user) => {
  user.value = _user;
});

const getUser = (): any => { //<-- What to use here instead of "any"
  return { user };
};

export default getUser;
```

I have tried using this:

```
const getUser = (): Ref<null | User> => {
  return { user };
};
```

And also this:

```
const getUser = (): { Ref<null | User> } => {
  return { user };
};
```

Both of them do not work.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out.

The problem was that the object `{ user }` is actually shorthand for `{ user: USER-KEY-VALUE-HERE }`. Which in my case was `{ user: Ref<User | null> }`.

Therefore the final return Type becomes:

```
const getUser = (): { user: Ref<User | null> } => {
  return { user };
};
```